# Is argv[argc] equal to NULL Pointer

Tags: c, linux, argv

I read an article (forgot the URL), which said that `argv[argc]` is a `NULL` pointer (contains `\0`). To check whether if its true I wrote this code, yeah it exist. What I don't understand is, why does the OS include this `NULL` pointer at `argv[argc]`. Is it useful for something else also?

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv){

    while (*argv)
        printf ("%s\n", *argv++);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*argv[0] shall be the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the name used to invoke the program or "". The value of argc shall be nonnegative. The value of argv[argc] shall be 0.*"

Answer (score 11):

The C Standard `5.1.2.2.1/2` second mark says explicitly

> argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

The C++ Standard `3.6.1/2` also says explicitly

> The value of argv[argc] shall be 0.

Comment: Yes, but what is the motivation for this?

Comment: Why is the sky blue? It's a null terminated array of null terminated arrays of `char`. I'd guess consistency and to facilitate code like the OP wrote.

Comment: See, you can do it. :-) Sounds like a good answer to me.

Comment: As for your question about the colour of the sky: http://www.sciencemadesimple.com/sky_blue.html

Comment: @rubenvb http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/General/BlueSky/blue_sky.html :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun slowpoke :)

Comment: According to me such rules are really helpful in writing better efficient code. And I guess only this is the reason why they included it. Thank you everyone. Have a great day.

Comment: This is what happens when the question title does not reflect the question body. @Thilo: Also: why then is the sky not violet? **Edit:** I see the second link intelligently answers that one.

Comment: @rubenvb 2 in 1: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090208215127AAdL1E6 But the first link I provided answers this.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/28895/why-is-the-sky-not-purple

Comment: Regarding blue sky: https://xkcd.com/1145/

Comment: I'm going to have to find better rethorical questions.

Answer (score 5):

The Standard (C99 5.1.2.2.1p2) mandates that:

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey
>   the following constraints:
>
> — The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
>
> — argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.
>
> ...

The rationale for this is to provide a redundant check for the end of the argument list, on the basis of common practice (ref: *Rationale for the ANSI C programming language (1990)*, 2.1.2.2).