# Seg Fault at end Main, GDB output provided

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, ncurses

Sorry, I'm new to c programming

As the title says, The code runs perfectly till the end of main where it returns 0. It then gives a seg fault with no reason why. Some answers said that maybe I wasnt freeing all that I malloced but I did. So I tried using gdb to figure out why. This was the first time I've ever used it.

This is the output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7644f1d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7644f1d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff76450aa in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff760365b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff76036f5 in exit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff75eaecc in __libc_start_main ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000000400bc9 in _start ()
```

My main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if(argv[1] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Please enter the path to the map generating file as an argument.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    run(getName(), argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

My program is a ncurses program, which i can (I believe I am) succesfully create the screen and then close it. I've checked that all the malloced variables have been freed as well.

Run is in a diffrent c file where I draw the ncurses board.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have undefined behavior when no argument is passed to the program.

Comment: @zenith sorry what do you mean? isnt that the null checker? or am i thinking of something else?

Comment: May be off topic,but  what is argument types of function `run`?

Comment: `argv[1] == NULL` should be `argc < 2`

Comment: It is possible that your `run()` method is corrupting the stack. Try to reproduce the problem with a simpler version of `run()`.

Comment: @Exikle Sorry my mistake, [`argv[argc]` *is* actually a null pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418932/is-argvargc-equal-to-null-pointer). You learn something new everyday...

Comment: Try to run it in valgrind

Comment: Given gdb output is not sufficient. May be you should use `list` and `run` commands on gdb to find on which line you are receiving Seg Fault

Answer (score 0):

It's not sure that gdb will give you the exact location when the corruption really happens. (the backtrace suggests it's a stack-related one)

For this kind of errors, the best tool is **Valgrind**, run your app with it.

(In my experience memory corruption errors could be tracked down and eliminated within minutes with Valgrind)