# Why is argv[argc] a pointer to NULL?

Tags: c, pointers, null, argv, argc

In the C standard ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), §5.1.2.2.1 - "Program startup", is written:

> 2  -  If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints:
>
> — *argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.*

---

My Question is:

- Why `char *argv[argc]`/`char **argv` shall be/ is a pointer to `NULL`?

This is what doesn´t make sense to me. `argv[]` is an array of pointers pointing to `char`. `argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers, pointing to `char`. Even if there are no flags given by the call, the pointer shouldn´t turn to a pointer to `NULL`.

Isn´t `char* argv[]` an array of pointers to `char` and `char **argv` a nested pointer to `char` pointers? How can a nested pointer to `char` (`char**`) be a pointer to `NULL`?

---

I have read the answers to [argv[argc] ==?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772796/argvargc) where the above-mentioned phrase from the standard is quoted as answers and also questioned to [@pmg´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772826/12139179), who gave me the answer:

> independent of the names used, by the c specification char *argv[argc] declares an array named argv capable of holding argc pointers to char. When passed to a function, the array gets converted to a pointer to its 1st element (so a pointer to pointer to char [this is why it is usual to see main(int argc, char **argv)]) losing information about size (char *a[10] has 10 elements; char **a is a pointer --- if the pointer points to an array, there is no way of knowing how many elements the underlying array has).

but unfortunately despite the humble effort, I still can´t understand why a pointer to pointer (nested pointer) to `char` (`char**`) turns into a pointer to `NULL`.

The answers to [Is argv[argc] equal to NULL Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418932/is-argvargc-equal-to-null-pointer) also do not answer **why** it shall be a pointer to `NULL`, only that **is** a pointer to `NULL` while quoting the above statement of the standard.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `argc` is the number of elements in the `argv` array, the highest index of a valid entry is `argc-1`. That is, the last "argument" is `argv[argc-1]`. Technically, that could make `argv[argc]` undefined. The choice was made to make it NULL. What this does is provide additional ways of looping through the argument list (checking for NULL instead of using `argc` as a loop count).

Comment: The "why" needs references to 1970's data/authors - else we are left with speculation.

Comment: Probably that may be explained by historical reasons, but I don't know what those are. That constraint allows loops to traverse all command line arguments using only `argv`: `while (*argv) puts(*argv++);`. Perhaps that kind of loops were widespread at the time of standardization process.

Comment: *The "why" needs references to 1970's data/authors*. Are you sure that `argv[argc]` has been implemented as NULL going back to the 1970's? :)

Comment: `argv[argc]` is not a pointer to `NULL`. It is a null pointer. Its **value** is `NULL`. It does not point to `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

It is done for two reasons:

1. For extra safety: if you try accessing an element beyond `[argc - 1]` you will crash, instead of interpreting garbage as an extra argument, and doing something bad with it, like treating it as a filename and writing to the file.
2. For convenience: this way, you can make use of `argv` without knowing `argc`.

How it works:

There is no magic really, here is the memory layout:

```
char**  |    char*     |  char[]
--------+--------------+---------
argv -> | argv[0] ->   | "arg1"
        | argv[1] ->   | "arg2"
        | argv[2] NULL |
```

Comment: This does not answer the question asked. This answers why `argv[argc]` is `NULL`, but the question asks (incorrectly) why `argv[argc]` is a pointer to `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

From

**Rationale for International Standard Programming Languages C
Revision 5.10
April-2003**

**5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**

> The specification of **argc** and **argv** as arguments to **main**
>   recognizes extensive prior practice. **argv[argc]** is required to be
>   a null pointer to provide a redundant check for the end of the list,
>   also on the basis of common practice.

---

**Update:**
As pointed out by Eric Postpischil, this answers why `argv[argc]` is a null pointer. Of course `argv[argc]` is **not** a *pointer to NULL*, as asked in the question (`NULL` is a macro defined as a null pointer constant; *pointer to NULL* makes no sense). So the question and answers may be rendered moot.

Answer (score 2):

What is meant by

> — argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.

Is that index `argc` of the array `argv` is a null pointer.

That is

```
if (argv[argc] == NULL)
```

will always come out true.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it is for convenience `while(*argv != NULL) ....`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the **why**.

The C standard did not invent this convention; it documented existing practice. In doing so, one of the goals was to let existing programs continue to work. Since there are existing programs that relied on `argc`, that parameter had to be conserved. And since there were other programs that relied on `argv[]` being NULL-terminated, that too had to be conserved.

The existing practice in turn was mostly an implementation detail of the early UNIX implementation.